# How to convert an integer scalar array in to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, casting

I would like to assign at `x[r,t+1]` a value take from a certain distribution:

`x[r,t+1] = np.random.choice(np.arange(C+1), size=1, p=P[x[r])`

but, when iI run the code above, I get:

*TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index*

I don't know why, because when I run (at example):

`np.random.choice(np.arange(C+1), size=1, p=P[3])`

this correctly returns a single value array.

I think that it could be caused by the `array` type, but I'm not sure about it.

**Add**:
I have tried to change `x` with `x[r]`, in order to obtain a full row of the matrix `x`:

```
x = np.zeros(10,15)).astype(int)

def MC_P(nr, tm):

  for r in list(range(nr)):
    x[r,0] = C
    for t in list(range(tr-1)):  
      x[r,t+1] = np.random.choice(np.arange(C+1), size=1, p=P[x[r]])

  return x

MC_P(10,15)
```

Comment: What is `x`, `r` and `t` here?

Comment: `x` is 2D a matrix, `r` and `t` are the indices

Comment: I would like to add `C` to that list.

Comment: Can you please provide an MWE?

Comment: @mapf I have modified `x`  the index of `P` as above.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry, I still cannot run your code. Can you modify it so that anyone can run it and reproduce the error?

Comment: @mapf Now the simplified code is runnable. The aforementioned part is about the implementation of `MonteCarlo` simulations.

Comment: What do `C`, `tr` and `P` look like? I am trying to run your code, but all these variables are not defined. Please provide some values, because I cannot come up with them myself. They don't have to be the *actual* values, only something close that reproduces the error.

Comment: Sorry, I have found that the error is about how to choose the correct line in `P`. I have solved using `P[x[r,t]]` instead of `P[x[r]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the error is about how to choose the correct line in P. I have solved using `P[x[r,t]]` instead of `P[x[r]]`.